# Using NSwag to generate a C# client incorrectly creates 2x partial classes with the same name, in the same file

Tags: c#, swagger, openapi, nswag

I'm trying to generate an NSwag C# Client, from an OpenAPI json file.

When I do this, I do get a client file generated, but it doesn't compile. It has created 2x partial classes in the same .cs file.

[image]

Now, if I change one of these class names to anything else, the file can now compile:

[image]

No errors - compiles OK.

So my question is: why is this doing it?

Here's a picture of my Swagger UI (this was generated with Swashbuckle, not NSwag):

[image]

So this means I have 2x controllers in the project:

- HomeController
- DocumentsController

Is there some trick to fixing this?

I used the following command line, to generate the client:

`dotnet-openapi --updateProject .\MyProject.csproj http://localhost:5100/swagger/v1/swagger.json`

Dotnet-openapi is using NSwag CSharpClientGenerator "under the hood", as far as I believe.

I'm happy to use any other tool to generate a C# client.

Comment: DId you get any solution?

Comment: I second that: Any Solution to that problem?

Comment: I third this. Just ran into the same issue. Curious if it is related to a Newtonsoft.Json update.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and was able to solve it after staring at the code for some time. The issue was that my endpoint had an underscore (`_`) in the uri, which nswag apparently don't get along with;

```
[HttpPost("a_bad_uri_with_underscore")]
public void SomeMethod() => _someHandler.Execute();
```

Typing an underscore was a mistake, my intention was to use dash (`-`) so once that was changed it worked.

```
[HttpPost("a-working-uri-with-dash")]
public void SomeMethod() => _someHandler.Execute();
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer helped and saved much time!

Answer (score 2):

This took a while to figure out. Other answers list setting `OperationGenerationMode.SingleClientFromOperationId` on the generator somehow, but I couldn't find how to do that. I examined the NSwag source to figure out how to set it.

```
var document = await OpenApiYamlDocument.FromFileAsync("api.yaml");

var settings = new CSharpClientGeneratorSettings()
{
    ClassName = "MyClient",
};
settings.CSharpGeneratorSettings.Namespace = "MyNamespace";

var generator = new CSharpClientGenerator(document, settings);

// How to Set SingleClientFromOperationId
generator.BaseSettings.OperationNameGenerator = new SingleClientFromOperationIdOperationNameGenerator();

var code = generator.GenerateFile();

File.WriteAllText("client.cs", code);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was to add NSWag CLI parameter: /OperationGenerationMode:SingleClientFromOperationId

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).